# Audio/Video DOM error Event doesn't work in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm trying to use `onerror` to detect when none of the sources provided in the audio tag are available/online. For some odd reason, it doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox but it works fine in Safari, Edge and IE. What's the reason behind this and how can I fix it?

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

audio.load();

// Can play
audio.oncanplay = function() {
  audio.play();
  console.log('Playing...');
};

// Cannot play
audio.onerror = function() {
  // error shows in Safari/IE/Edge but not in Chrome/Firefox
  console.log('Error! sources are not available');
};
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horseX.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horseX.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<!-- Remove X from url for working mp3 samples -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'error' event  should be attached on the source element in Google Chrome and Firefox. To handle the error event on multiple sources, you must bind the error handle to the last source.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I too had the same problem which was fixed by attaching the error event to source instead of `<audio>` tag

Comment: It did not work for me in chrome. The only way I'm able to attach error handling is:

var aud = new Audio(src); aud.addEventListener('error', errorHandler);